# Is value in array or string inside object Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

A little bit of an odd one here, I’m working with parsing query strings and sometimes they are returned as strings and other times as arrays of strings (depending on if there’s one vs. many).

I want to find out whether the value exists under the key, and it needs to work when the data is empty or null.

```
# we have access to both the key and value
const key = 'locations'
const value = 'London'
```

The shape of the data looks like:

```
# does 'London' exist under `locations`?
{
  locations: 'London',
  skills: ['1', '2'],
}
```

The shape of the data could also look like:

```
{
  locations: ['London', 'Reading'],
  skills: '1',
}
```

I’ve looked at using `pathSatisfies`, `pathEq` and `contains` but with no luck. I seem to be getting stumped on the fact the value can be contained in either a string or in an array.

Comment: `Array.isArray(locations)` will return `true` if it's an array, and `false` if it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a lens to convert the key into an array if it wasn't one already. Then you can simply use `propSatisfies` with `includes`:

```js
const toArr = unless(is(Array), of);

const check = (key, value) =>
  pipe(
    over(lensProp(key), toArr),
    propSatisfies(includes(value), key));

console.log(
  check('locations', 'London')({locations: ['London', 'Reading']})
);

console.log(
  check('locations', 'London')({locations: 'London'})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {unless, is, of, pipe, over, lensProp, propSatisfies, includes} = R;</script>
```

---

**EDIT:** Actually this can be simplified as `includes` work with both strings and arrays:

```js
const check = (key, value) => where({[key]: includes(value)})

console.log(
  check('locations', 'London')({locations: 'London'})
);

console.log(
  check('locations', 'London')({locations: ['London', 'Reading']})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {where, includes} = R;</script>
```

Comment: One potential problem with the simplified approach: `check('locations', 'York')({locations: 'New York'}) //=> true`

Comment: Oh god! Thank you @ScottSauyet for pointing this out. Out of curiosity do you think this could be a use case for `lift` maybe?

Comment: I don't see how.  Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments use `Array.isArray()` to see if the property contains an array and use array methods if it does, otherwise compare value directly

```js
const key = 'locations',
  value = 'London',
  data = {
    locations: 'London',
    skills: ['1', '2'],
  },
  data2 = {
    locations: ['London', 'Reading'],
    skills: '1',
  }

const hasValue = (data, key, value) => {
  const testVal = data[key];
  return Array.isArray(testVal) ? testVal.includes(value) : testVal === value;
}

// string version
console.log(hasValue(data, key, value));
   // array version
console.log(hasValue(data2, key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

This little function should get you there.

```
function hasValue(obj, key, value) {
    if (!obj) return false;
    let prop = obj[key];
    if (!prop) return false;
    if (Array.isArray(prop))
        return prop.indexOf(value) >= 0;
    return prop === value;
}
```